# can someone explain this code in chef template

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

can someone explain this code in chef template?  I would like to add an if condition to just variable2 . how do I approach this?

```
<%= @variable1 %>/*[!.][!g][!z] <%= @variable2 %>/*[!.][!g][!z] {
some random data in file

}
```

Comment: If you can update the question with some context and what you would like to achieve - it will attract better answer(s). This is within a `.erb` file right? What condition would you like to add to `variable2`?

Comment: Hi @seshadri_c, Thanks for responding ! I would like to understand this portion first ```/*[!.][!g][!z] ``` . And I would like to add if condition for variable2 . Let me know if this is still unclear .

Comment: Yes , this is an erb file .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so in a Chef template (`.erb` file) anything *outside* the markers `<%= ... %>` and `<% ... %>` is plain text, i.e. it will be rendered *as-is* on the destination.

- So `/*[!.][!g][!z]`  *inside* the `.erb` file has no meaning. Once it is rendered on the destination, it may have relevance. And what it will do at the destination depends on what type of file it is, and what's going to use the file.
- `<%= @variable1 %>` is to interpolate the value of `variable1`. Using `<% ... %>` will allow you to run Ruby script, i.e. `if/else` conditions, `for` loops etc.